# Customizing the keyboard "enter" button in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new in Android programming, but I have already made a little application. It has an `EditText` and a `Button`, `Okay`. The input for the EditText is set to `number`. When the user taps the `enter` button on the keyboard, I want to have the same action as if the `Okay` is clicked. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {           

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && 
            keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

            // do what you do in "Okay" button
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two steps:

1. Capture the 'enter' button press using onKeyDown() method of Activity. TextWatcher on your EditText may also be useful.
2. Then hide the soft keyboard using InputMethodManager's hideSoftInputFromWindow() method.

I haven't given any code snippets as you can easily google these two points

Comment: but, please, can you write a code snippet specific to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use TextWatcher like this:

```
            mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                     for(int i = s.length(); i > 0; i--){

                            //examine if user presses enter
                            if(s.subSequence(i-1, i).toString().equals("\n"))
                                 //do your action here

                        }

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int count, int after) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int before, int count) {


                }

            });
```

So this way, anytime you press the enter while writing in the EditText you can act as you wish.